# Why is my model giving different results in tensorflow.js and in Python Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to adapt the notebook "[Predict Artist from Artworks](https://www.kaggle.com/nageshsingh/eda-predict-artist-from-artworks-imagenet)" to my own dataset. The Keras model has been generated and converted to a Tensorflow model (using `tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras us.keras tfjs_model/us`), and I now try to use it with tensorflow.js, but the predictions results are different (and wrong) when using tensorflow.js.

Here is the prediction Python code which gives a correct result:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

artists = ['CB', 'AT', 'TS', 'FG', 'DR']

model = keras.models.load_model('us.keras')

image_file = 'datasets/full/thumbnails3/fr/gb/fr_gb_0004p_001.jpg'
test_image = image.load_img(image_file, target_size=(224, 224))

# Predict artist
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image /= 255.
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)

prediction = model.predict(test_image)
prediction_probability = np.amax(prediction)
prediction_idx = np.argmax(prediction)

print("Predicted artist = {}, probability of {:.2f} %"
      .format(artists[prediction_idx],  prediction_probability * 100))
```

The result is:

> Predicted artist = CB, probability of 22.62 %

However, when using tensorflow.js the results are completely different:

```
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
const tfn = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const sharp = require('sharp');

const modelFile = tfn.io.fileSystem("tfjs_model/us/model.json");

const artists = ['CB', 'AT', 'TS', 'FG', 'DR']

tf.loadLayersModel(modelFile).then(model => {
    sharp('datasets/full/thumbnails3/fr/gb/fr_gb_0004p_001.jpg')
        .rotate()
        .resize(224, 224)
        .toBuffer().then(
            data => {
                let image = tfn.node.decodeImage(data, 0)
                image = tf.expandDims(image, 0);
                image = tf.cast(image, 'float32').div(255)
                const prediction = model.predict(image);
                prediction.array().then(([predictionArray]) => {
                    const predictionProbability = Math.max(...predictionArray);
                    const predictionIndex = predictionArray.indexOf(predictionProbability);
                    console.log(`Predicted artist = ${artists[predictionIndex]}, probability of ${predictionProbability * 100}%`)
                })
            }
        )
})
```

Result:

> Predicted artist = DR, probability of 37.461987137794495%

My assumption is that something that I do with the dimensions or the handling of the image is wrong in the JS code, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: It surely has to do with the way the image is processed before the prediction. In the js, you are rotating the image before the prediction. You don't seem to be doing the same thing in python

Answer (score 1):

It surely has to do with the way the image is processed before the prediction. In js, you are rotating the image before the prediction. You don't seem to be doing the same thing in python.

Additionnally, you don't need the extra library `sharp` to load your image

```
const buf = fs.readFileSync('path/to/image');
const tensor = tfnode.node.decodeImage(buf, 3);
let resized = tensor.resizeBilinear([224, 224]).div(tf.scalar(255));
// ... the rest
```

The above is just a way to improve the code, not to say that `sharp` is the one causing the predictions not to match

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll give it a try